# it is possible to create managed package in scratch org with VS code

Tags: community, managed-package, salesforce1-app, package

AM trying to create a new managed package in scratch but it is invisible in scratch org.

[image]

there is any possible any?...

Comment: You cannot create 1GP managed packages in scratch orgs. Instead you create 2GPs using sfdx packaging commands.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no. You cannot create a managed package through the Setup UI on scratch orgs (though you can install other packages on a scratch org).

There are two types of managed package: first generation and second generation.

A first generation package (1GP) requires a persistent "release org" on which the package is built (typically via the Setup UI). This "release org" is also the "owner" of the namespace. A scratch org is not persistent (they disappear after a maximum of 30 days) so cannot host a 1GP.

A second generation package (2GP) requires a persistent "namespace org" that is the "owner" of the namespace, but the package itself is simply the required package directory that is part of your source tree and as defined in the sfdx-project.json. For the "namespace org" with the created namespace to operate, you must have registered it with your dev hub (for a partner this is the PBO, for others this is any [developer] org you want). See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_create_namespace.htm) for details.

2GPs are not visible through the Setup UI. You "view" meta information about them using the sfdx package commands (see below). Their content (your "source of truth" of what is packaged) exists in your source control system - this is a major change from 1GPs where the "source of truth" is the packaging org.

Everything you need to do is described in the [developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_before.htm).

It is worth noting that 2GPs support:

- Major and minor releases.
- Patches, if the 2GP has been through security review with Salesforce.
- Beta releases.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_comparison.htm) covers differences between 1GP and 2GP. You'll also find reference material for the [sfdx package commands](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm). It is also worth being aware of the [metadata coverage report](https://mdcoverage.secure.force.com/docs/metadata-coverage).

Comment: I have created a package by using Sfdx commands, but I don't know where to view my managed package in scratch org. @Phil W

Comment: As per my update: 2GPs are not visible through the Setup UI. You "view" meta information about them using the sfdx package commands. Their content (your "source of truth" of what is packaged) exists in your source control system - this is a major change from 1GPs where the "source of truth" is the packaging org.

Comment: actually, my requirement is I have created a dashboard in the Analytics Studio in scratch, so I need to create a new managed package and store the dashboard in the managed app and I need to deployed code in Vscode by using scratch org

Comment: can you help me out...I have created the dashboard and dataset in  Analytics Studio by using scratch.so I need to deploy the code in vs code. can you help @Phil W

Comment: If it's even available via sfdx, you will need to pull the metadata off the scratch org, put it in your package directory that forms your package and add it to your version control system then create a new version of your 2GP managed package that includes it.

Comment: I have doubts on that, how to create a 2GP managed package, and how to add the dashboard into scratch can you help me out to deploy the code @Phil W

Comment: `sfdx force:source:pull` will retrieve packageable metadata. I don't know if Analytics Studio stuff is packageable. Look at the metadata coverage report I referenced at the end of the answer.

Comment: (IIRC there are some specialist "einstein" related sfdx commands/plugins - please research for yourself starting from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference.htm)).